# How do I install a missing Python dependency that is already a system package (and detected by pip install)?

Tags: macos, python-2.7, homebrew

I installed Python/pip with Homebrew, then installed Pandas with pip. However, when I import Pandas, it says there is a missing dependency "pytz".

So I run

```
pip install pytz
```

But it thinks it already exists

```
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
```

Removing pytz does not work, when I run pip uninstall pytz, I get permission errors. How should I handle this?

Comment: Use a Python virtual environment and install packages into that instead. I have posted about some of the reasons why you shouldn't rely on system Python in http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2016/01/python-virtual-environments-and-docker.html You are experiencing a related issue. Ignore that post talks about Docker, is still relevant.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I use virtual environment for standalone projects. However, I'm trying to install Rodeo https://www.yhat.com/products/rodeo, which uses whatever Python is in $PATH. That means that the dependencies for Rodeo need to be installed for the System python (or whichever is in the $PATH). What should I do in this case?

Comment: The problem is that ``pytz`` is provided as part of the operating system Python. You can't uninstall it without upsetting anything in the operating system that requires it. Can you clarify ``which pip`` was being used when installing ``numpy`` and then ``pytz``. If you are running ``pip`` from Homebrew, it shouldn't be looking at the system Python packages.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I think that is my problem. `which pip` yields `/usr/local/bin/pip`, which I believe was installed by Homebrew. Yet `pip install pytz` reults in `Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python`. :-|

Answer (score 0):

For those interested: I re-installed python/pip with brew again and got this working. Even though Python and pip were in the right directory (`/usr/local/bin`), Pip was still looking for dependencies in `/System`. Pip stopped looking in `/System` after the reinstallation.